# Trying to install Dual Boot Win 10/Ubuntu 16.04 but fails

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows

I have Windows 10 installed on my Dell 5510 with a 1TB M.2 SSD. I am booting from a USB to install Ubuntu 16.04 and get the following error:

```
Unable to install GRUB in /dev/nvme Executing 'grub-install/dev/nvme' failed This is a fatal error
```

I have tried to make my own partition table but then when I reboot I do not get the "grub" menu where you can select which OS to boot into.

The option to install Ubuntu alongside windows is available because I split the HD already in Windows

Comment: Try to specify /dev/nvme0n1 for grub's install target.

Comment: Are you booting installer in UEFI mode, so grub is installed to ESP, not to MBR? May be best to see details:
Post the link to the Create BootInfo summary report. Is part of Boot-Repair:
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Info

Comment: @neofug Figured it out, had to boot into live version of Ubuntu and run boot-repair on the windows partition

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue but this is how i navigated my way through.

1. I remove my pendrive, i boot into the windows and Use **PowerISO** to create a bootable media. I recreated the whole Ubuntu 16 on the **New** bootable  media. in some instances try changing the pendrive.

   2. Then opened disk management on the windows, right click on the partition on which you want to install ubuntu and delete and it would appear **unallocated**.
   3. Time to Reboot with your pendrive. The point when you would choose partitions, just look through the options and use the **Use Continuous Free Space** option. Make Sure to install the Grub to the Main Hardrive, Ubuntu would scan your drive and prompt you to install the Grub bootloader to the main drive at the end of the installation. ##please check your system, Uefi or efi

Comment: So its UEFI, but the boot is set to Legacy